# Could not process parameters: str() it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Tags: python, mysql, string, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

This isnt working and is showing the error "Could not process parameters: str(Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland), it must be of type list, tuple or dict"

```
import mysql.connector
from sentence_splitter import SentenceSplitter, split_text_into_sentences

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="00.00.00.00",
  user="user",
  password="password",
  database="database"
)


mycursor = mydb.cursor()


sql = ("""SELECT blog_paragraph FROM blog_paragraph WHERE blog_topic like '%"%s"%'""")
val = ("Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland")
mycursor.execute(sql,val)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
      print(x)
```

However, when the value is directly passed in the query it seems to run without any errors.

```
import mysql.connector
from sentence_splitter import SentenceSplitter, split_text_into_sentences

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="00.00.00.00",
  user="user",
  password="password",
  database="database"
)


mycursor = mydb.cursor()


sql = ("""SELECT blog_paragraph FROM blog_paragraph WHERE blog_topic like '%"Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland"%'""")
mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
      print(x)
```

Tried passing string parameters through a variable and is not seeming to be working.

**Found the answer later**

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

val = "Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland"
sql = ("SELECT blog_paragraph FROM blog_paragraph WHERE blog_topic like '%%%s%%'  " % val)

mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states:

> "Could not process parameters: str(Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland), it must be of type list, tuple or dict"

your parameters must be one of the expected types but you are sending `str`

you included the parenthesis on the `val` variable:

```
val = ("Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland")
```

But `tuples` are defined by the commas `,` not the parenthesis, this should work:

```
val = ("Providing Quality Tyre Services in Ponteland",)
```

Comment: It removed the error but it is returning an empty print now. Nothing is printing